# Need explanation of proof of Theorem 3 in Section 31, Chapter II of Kuratowski's Topology

Tags: metric-spaces, borel-sets

When I read Chapter II, Section 31: "B-measurable Functions" in Topology by Kuratowski, I have a problem in understanding the proof of Theorem 3.
Here is the image of that theorem.

[image]

I can not understand the left direction proof ($\Leftarrow$), which I marked with a blue line, especially the last sentence: "Secondly, the condition ...". 
There is written *"for sufficiently large $k$, if $|y-f(x)|<\frac{1}{k}$, then $y\in G$ (since $G$ open)."*
I can not connect it with the definition of open set, i.e. the set G is open if for every $z\in G$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(z,r)\subset G$.
So, can anyone explain, why if $G$ is open, implies that, for sufficiently large $k$, if $|y-f(x)|<\frac{1}{k}$, then $y\in G$?
Thanks for any explanation.

**Note:**
Definition of B-measurable function

> A mapping $f:X\to Y$ is said to be B-measurable of class $a$ (or, briefly, of class $a$) if, for every closed subset $F\subset Y$, the set $f^{-1}(F)$ is borelian of multiplicative class $a$.

And $\delta[A]$ denotes diameter of set $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He wants to show

$$f^{-1}(G) = Z := \bigcup\{Z^k_n \mid f(Z^k_n) \subset G \} .$$
By definition $Z \subset f^{-1}(G)$ since $f(Z^k_n) \subset G$ is equivalent to $Z^k_n \subset f^{-1}(G)$.

Next he considers $x \in f^{-1}(G)$ which is equivalent to $f(x) \in G$. Since $G$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(f(x),r) \subset G$. This means that if $\lvert y - f(x) \rvert < r$, then $y \in G$. Now we may take w.l.o.g. $r = 1/k$ for some sufficiently large $k$. We know that $x \in Z^k_n$ for some $n$. Since $\delta(f(Z^k_n)) < 1/k$, we get $\lvert f(x) - f(x') \rvert < 1/k$ for all $x' \in Z^k_n$. Thus $f(x') \in G$ for all $x' \in Z^k_n$, i.e. $f(Z^k_n) \subset G$. This shows that $x \in Z^k_n \subset Z$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is clearer for me.  In the proof, he uses $\delta(f(Z_n^k))<\frac{1}{k}$, but, in the theorem is written $\delta(f(Z_n))<\varepsilon$. Then, may I take $r=\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user136524 Yes, of course!